# How do i find the product key of Windows 10 (OEM Sticker Erased)

Tags: windows-10

I have upgraded from windows 7. MY OEM sticker has been Erased.
I want save my Product key of windows 10. I am going to clean install it.
what is command or Gui method to find the Product which is already installed.

Comment: I have upgraded from windows 7. MY OEM sticker has Erased as it has been old. By Nirsoft Product Key I found my Product key. So I will use the same when I install Windows 10 again.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I don't want to find the Windows 7 key. See after I upgrade to windows 10. My Product key is Changed to something. As my system is slow I wanted to clean install  with windows 10. While installing the Windows 10 it prompt to Product key. So I wanted key so I can use during installation. That's it.

Comment: @user749320 If you've already activated Windows 10 on that machine just chose to skip this step. Once you're up and running, you can start the activation process and Microsoft will spot that your machine already has a valid licence without you needing to provide a licence key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

First Method:

> 1. Download Produkey utility tool from nirsoft  (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/produkey-x64.zip)
> 2. Run ProductKey.exe.

You'll be able to find product key.

Second method:

> 1. Open 'Run' (Press Windows key + R)
> 2. Type: `slui.exe 4` then hit Enter
> 3. Select your country from the list menu
> 4. choose the option phone activation, then wait for an agent to assist you.