# Activate Windows pops up after latest Insider update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation, windows-insider

I am an Insider on the Fast pace for Active Development of Windows. 5 days ago, I had installed the latest Insider update released on 13th December, 2017 (`Build:17063.rs_prerelease.171213-1610`). After updating to that, Windows has been saying that my product license is not valid and is asking me to buy a genuine copy form the Store.

The error code is:

> 0x803F7001

Before this, everything was fine and Windows was activated. I bought this machine with Windows 10 pre-installed. Previously, this same problem had occurred in which Windows was not activated after installing an Insider patch, but it resolved itself in 2 days. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: You will need to activate your installation by phone.

Comment: @Ramhound okay, how?

Comment: ‘slui.exe 4’ will start the process or go to Settings as instructed

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1229462/how-do-i-find-the-product-key-of-windows-10-oem-sticker-erased/1229473#1229473

Comment: Being an Insider means assuming the risk, but also the responsibility for reporting this bug to Microsoft.

Comment: @harrymc already reported, i'm also trying to find a solution, so thought i would ask the community at large

Comment: this is a known issue in last insider preview: ["ADDED 12/21: We are investigating reports that Windows shows that it “needs activation” and trying to activate fails after upgrading to Build 17063."](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/12/19/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17063-pc/#AloFO4CroASJoDeW.97)